# Perl: adding matching strings in RE

Tags: regex, perl

Here is a perl RE that will increment a number in angle brackets.

```
echo "aaa build<23>bbb')"|perl -p -e 's/^(.*build<)(\d+)(>.*)$/$2 + 1/e;'
24
```

How can I get this effect and also keep the contents of the line before and after the angle brackets? Just adding `$1` and `$3` does not work.

```
echo "aaa build<23>bbb')"|perl -p -e 's/^(.*build<)(\d+)(>.*)$/$1$2 + 1$3/e;'
Scalar found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "$1$2"
    (Missing operator before $2?)
Scalar found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "1$3"
    (Missing operator before $3?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "$1$2 "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use captured groups like this:

```
echo "aaa build<23>bbb')"|perl -pe 's/^(.*build<)(\d+)(>.*)$/$1 . ($2+1) . $3/e;'
aaa build<24>bbb')
```

- Concatenate string variables using DOT
- Do math operations using +`

Answer (score 2):

I use `\K` and positive lookahead.

```
echo "aaa build<23>bbb')"| perl -p -e 's/^(?:.*build<)\K(\d+)(?=>.*$)/$1 + 1/e;'
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/HvxJZF)

- `\K` discards the previously matched characters from printing at the final.
- `(?=>.*$)` Positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by certain characters.

Answer (score 2):

Only increase the *first* number between `<` and `>` by one:

```
echo "aaa build<23>bbb')" | perl -pE 's/(?<=<)(\d+)(?=>)/$1 + 1/e'
```

see `perldoc perlre` for the explains of `(?<=PATTERN)` and `(?=PATTERN)`. (Hint: Searching 'Look-Around Assertions' in perlre.)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Avinash Raj , but TIMTOWTDI :-)

This solution is, in my opinion, closer to the question. Use positive lookahead and lookbehind assertions, instead of trying to match the whole line, as you did (by enclosing everyting with `^` and `$`):

```
 echo "aaa build<23>bbb')"|perl -p -e 's/(?<=build<)(\d+)(?=>)/$1 + 1/e;'
```

Which gives

```
aaa build<24>bbb')
```

If you expect more than one occurrence of `build<>` expression in one line, use the `g` modifier.